# Can someone explain how the c++ operator= here works?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

I have this small c++ code snippet, may someone explain how the operator= works here ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

    using namespace std;

    static wstring & test() {
        static wstring test2;
        return test2;
   };


   int main()
   {
       test() = L"Then!";
       wcerr << test() << endl;
   }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/7571258

Comment: I don't understand what your actual question is. The `=` operator assigns one thing to another. How is that confusing?

Comment: This seems like your *real* question regards how *references* work in C++; not assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The function `test()` is returning a reference (not a copy) to the static variable `test2`. The static keyword makes the function `test` maintain the value of variable `test2` between calls. Hence when you call `test()` it returns the reference allowing you to change the value of `test2` inside the `test()`. This results in `wcerr << test2 << endl;` printing out "Then!"

Note the static keyword has different meaning depending on the context. Making the function static makes the the function only visible to other functions in the file. If you put a static function in a header you will have deceleration for that function for each #include of that header.

What you probably wanted to say is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

wstring & test() {
   static wstring test2;
   return test2;
}

int main()
{
   test() = L"Then!";
   wcerr << test() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `test()` returns a *reference* to the `static` variable `test2`.  A reference refers to a variable; you could substitute the variable in place of the reference.

This is equivalent to the code:

```
static wstring test2;
int main()
{
    test2 = L"Then!";
    wcerr << test2 << endl;
}
```

Search your favorite C++ reference for "references".

Comment: On the VC++ compiler, the '=' is definited as std::wstring::operator=(const wchar_t *_Ptr) so is overloaded. What I don't understand is how work the assignment, test() = L"Then!";. test() is a function, how is possible to set the static wstring inside the function ?

Comment: @UnoSolo Do you know what a [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) is in C++?

Comment: @UnoSolo it returns a reference to a `wstring`, so the assignment is performed on the object the reference refers to (i.e. the `wstring`)

Comment: It'd be interesting to hear the reasoning behind the downvote.